# MFC about Create regedit key, in local machine is work, but at other machine or os is not work

Tags: mfc, regedit

I create regedit key named "Language" in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SOFTWARE\Company\Company\, in visual studio debug mode will be create, but I build it through Install shield, and Install it in other machine and OS (windows 7 window 8), the key can't create by application.

When step of Install shield, I create Regedit key of SOFTWARE\Company\Company\,
But I can't Change the key of Language at this code

```
SetMainRegeditValue(theApp.mMainRegKey, theApp.mMainRegNormal[0], theApp.g_eLanguage);
```

what happen with this code ?

```
// In the global 
CRegKey mMainRegKey;
CString *mMainRegPath;
CString *mMainRegNormal;

....

theApp.mMainRegPath = new CString[1];
theApp.mMainRegPath[0] = _T("SOFTWARE\\Company\\Company\\");

theApp.mMainRegNormal = new CString[1];
theApp.mMainRegNormal[0] = _T("Language");

// Check Regedit value
if(theApp.mMainRegKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, theApp.mMainRegPath[0]) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    TCHAR  tstrLan[_MAX_PATH];

    DWORD len = _MAX_PATH;
    DWORD lanlen = 8;
    if(theApp.mMainRegKey.QueryStringValue(_T("Version"),tstrLan, &lanlen) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, theApp.mMainRegPath[0]);
        RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, theApp.mMainRegNormal[0]);

        SetMainRegeditValue(theApp.mMainRegKey,_T("Version"), _T("v2.0.0"));
    }
}

if(theApp.mMainRegKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,theApp.mMainRegPath[0]) != ERROR_SUCCESS)     
{
    theApp.mMainRegKey.Create(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, theApp.mMainRegPath[0]);
    SetMainRegeditValue(theApp.mMainRegKey, theApp.mMainRegNormal[0], theApp.g_eLanguage);
}
```

Comment: You need administrator privileges to write anything to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find the rule.
need administrator privileges to write anything to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
but HKEY_CURRENT_USER not necessary, so replace HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
the problem be solved.